# Get a distinct list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to select a distinct list.

The following code is not working:

```
public IQueryable<BusinessObjects.Order> GetByBusinessId(Guid Id)
    {
        rentalEntities db = DataContextFactory.CreateContext();

        List<Rental.BusinessObjects.Order> transformedList = new List<BusinessObjects.Order>();
        foreach (Rental.DataObjects.EntityModel.Order item in db.Orders.Where(x => x.BusinessID == BusinessId).ToList())
        {
            transformedList.Add(OrderMappers.ToBusinessObject(item));
        }
        return( transformedList.AsQueryable()).Distinct();
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: try applying `Distinct` to the query itself `db.Orders.Where(x => x.BusinessID == BusinessId).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Why are you calling AsQueryable? And why aren't you using Select and ToList to convert to a list in the first place? How do you want to detect "equal" entities?

Comment: I am trying to get all the customer for the particular business from order table {where customer making order} 
But many customer making many order so the list is include duplicated value again and again

Comment: What do you count as a "duplicate" value though? If a customer has several orders, surely those should count as separate orders...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Rental.DataObjects.EntityModel.Order item in db.Orders
  .Where(x => x.BusinessID == BusinessId)
   .Distinct()
    .Select(item => OrderMappers.ToBusinessObject(item));
```

This should move the distinct operation to the underlying database call as it's applied before the query is materialized - this is more efficient as the duplicate rows aren't retrieved from the database server.  If for some reason you don't want to do that, then check your equals implementation (as mentioned by Sorin)

Comment: thanx Nathan i try this but it not working                                  
return transformedList.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.BusinessID == BusinessId).Distinct();

Comment: Your question needs more information about the error(s) you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check how your business objects implement Equals(), my guess is they are are different even if they have (let's say) the same ID.

Comment: I am trying to get all the customer for the particular business from order table {where customer making order} 
But many customer making many order so the list is include duplicated value again and again

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try the DistinctBy() extension method from the MoreLinq library.  This lets you easily control the exact semantics of how two objects are compared for distinctness.  For instance:

```
return transformedList.AsQueryable().DistinctBy(orderBO => orderBO.OrderId);
```

http://morelinq.googlecode.com/files/morelinq-1.0-beta.zip